# jdbcTemplate and pagination

Tags: sql-server, pagination, jdbctemplate

I am trying to modify parts of some pre-existing code to return a Page and use Pageable. However I am at a loss as to how to approach this. From the little I found I need to have "Limit" and "Offset", but am using SQL Server which doesn't recognize the syntax.

```
public List<TotalForAllDTO> findAll() {
    String query = queryProps.getProperty("findAll");
    return jdbcTemplate.query(query, new Object[]{}, new TotalForAllDTOMapper());
```

Any guidance would be very helpful.